# Unwanted word wrapping in some browsers - why is this rendered differently?

Tags: html, css, menu, cross-browser

I'm having problems with the menus of a site I'm developing. Here's what the menus look like in different browsers.

**Chrome 5**

[image: Chrome]

**Opera 10**

[image: Opera]

**Firefox 4 Beta 2**

[image: Firefox]

**Internet Explorer 8**

[image: Internet Explorer]

The menu looks okay in Chrome, but in some browsers the little arrow is wrapped onto the next line. Additionally, in Firefox and IE the menu item overlaps with the arrow. How do I fix this?

You can find the stylesheet, HTML sources and all that jazz here:
[http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/vspwpg/](http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/vspwpg/?page_id=96)

Comment: ... have you tried making the font-size smaller?

Comment: If you're using tables to render the drop-down, the TD tag has a NOWRAP attribute. Also there is the NOBR tag. But I'm not sure if these are standard enough for your use.

Comment: Making the font smaller won't help because the width of all my menus is calculated so that the widest menu item will always fit. I'm using `<li>`s, not `<td>`s.

Comment: I think you should skip using the `»` character as a menu indicator, and instead use a background image instead. Giving the anchor more padding on the right side to accommodate for the image, and we could avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: Good advice, Yi. I think I'm gonna implement that in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in file style.css add `width:100%` in `ul#menu > li > ul li`

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the float: right in the span behind the menu item with the double arrow in it (class sf-sub-indicator). Floating it will allow the contents to overlap the way they do now, because it takes the element out of the flow.

You'll find the theory behind floating elements here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

hmmm what if you change your span for the little arrows " >> " to this

```
ul#menu > li > ul > li a > span.sf-sub-indicator {
margin-left:5px;
position:absolute;
right:5px;
}
```

and you add more padding-right to the li

```
ul#menu > li > ul li {
...
padding-right:20px;
...
}
```

it works in FF, but i'm not sure for the others